# Word or phrase for a person who does something because a loved one asks, not because it's necessarily correct

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a way to describe someone who does something not because it's correct, but because someone they care about asked them to. For example:

> "Please keep the light on so the monsters can't get me," said the boy. And his mother did, for she was a _____ woman"

I've thought of **loyal**, but that doesn't exactly get across that they are only doing it because it is more important to them to take care of their loved one than be correct.

In addition, a word describing the sort of request itself would be very helpful. Such as

> "She obliged his ____ request"

Answer (score 1):

There are really two different tacks you can take here:

[Doting](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/doting) for example, implies “excessively fond” and the implication can easily be taken to the extreme of doing things out of love rather than propriety.

> He was cared for by his doting mother who acceded to his every whim.

Or you can take it from the standpoint of the asker being the ridiculous one:

> His loving mother saw to his every whim and desire no matter how eccentric.

Answer (score -1):

"**Understanding**" seem to connote precisely enough the idea explained.

> [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/understanding_2) *understanding* showing sympathy for other people’s problems and being willing to forgive them when they do something wrong

- And his mother did, for she was an understanding woman.

There is no single adjective that will describe the child's request.

- **childish, ridiculous, laughable, absurd, ...**
- She obliged his *absurd* request.